# Excel delete column with win32com

Tags: python-3.x, excel, win32com

I could not find one adequate documentation for the win32com library
Can you please tell me how to delete a column in Excel using this library?
I guess it looks something like this:

```
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path_on_file)
ws = wb.Worksheet("Sheet1")
ws.DeleteColumn(1, 3)
```

But how exactly can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the same COM objects that VBA would access, so you can simply refer to the [VBA docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel/object-model).

There you will find that you can [get the column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.columns) or [range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.range) that you want and then [delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.delete) it as follows:

```py
for i in range(3, 0, -1):
  ws.Columns(i).Delete()

# or

ws.Range("A:C").Delete()
```

Note that for the individual deletions, I'm deleting them backwards, otherwise the indices would shift during deletion.

Also, you have a typo in your code, it should be `.Worksheets("Sheet1")` with "worksheets" as plural.